Manhwa where "10000 worlds collapse into one"
I found a link to a manhwa on YouTube. 10000 worlds collapsed into one and the main character (with others) got transported to some random territory. The protagonist goes to a weak plant territory




I'm reasonably certain that this is some sort of AI-generated artwork, possibly an original work by the person who's posted the video. Whenever I do a search for screenshots, I keep getting led to the same Tensor.AI and AI artist websites; https://i.sstatic.net/ccAQs.png

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@Community - It's perfectly clear what he's asking. Silly robot

@BlackDrago - OK. I've done a little digging. The person who posted this video specalises in taking Chinese-language, fan-written webnovels from mtlnation.com and shuqi.com. They use an AI tool from a site called Tensor.AI to make generic looking panels for the video. He's also changing the names and some of the character descriptions around.

In conclusion, there's almost certainly a webnovel based on this work, but it's unlikely to be in English and the images are completely original to the video, but dynamically generated by an AI tool

Their intro video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUB5Uta0kds suggests they make at least some of them up from whole cloth, although maybe "script writers" here is closer to "translators" or even "we ripped this off from a poor author, but we'd prefer to say we wrote it".

I dnt think they wrote posted novels themselves bcz many commented they found many other videos with same content in defferent channels

An anonymous user has attempted to edit this answer to state that the answer is the web novel, Lord of the People: My Troops Have Mutated. To said user: if you believe that is that is the correct answer, you should post it as an actual answer (using the 'Your Answer' field below), rather than editing it into the question. We like questions and answers to be posted separately on this site, not combined into one.
